# Combining attributes of SetEnvIF in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, setenv

I would like to combine the following `SetEnvIF` configuration into single line. Is it possible to do so?

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For ^(91\.148\.158\.226|77\.70\.95\.131) TRUSTED_IPS
SetEnvIf X-Real-IP ^(91\.148\.158\.226|77\.70\.95\.131) TRUSTED_IPS
```

Comment: Are you running out of newlines? `SetEnvIf` and `SetEnvIfNoCase` syntax `SetEnvIf attribute regex [!]env-variable[=value] [[!]env-variable[=value]] ...` doesn't allow you to combine attributes. However you can set the same variable in as many `SetEnIf`directives as you want and it will work exactly the same way in `allow`/`deny`. Having separated lines also increases readability. I just can't figure out the purpose for this request.

Comment: Hi @EsaJokinen

Purpose is to avoid having the same IPs on two lines.

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs, the `attribute` of the directive actually accepts a regex, but no example is given in its section. Rather one can be seen under [Environment Variables > Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html#examples). In your case it would be:

```
SetEnvIF ^X-(?:Forwarded-For|Real-IP)$ ^(91\.148\.158\.226|77\.70\.95\.131) TRUSTED_IPS
```

Answer (score -1):

As this wouldn't be a problem with just one pair of IP addresses I assume you have many IP addresses you would like to go through without adding them all on two separate lines.

As [`SetEnvIf` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) only has one correct syntax,

```
SetEnvIf attribute regex [!]env-variable[=value] [[!]env-variable[=value]] ...
```

it is not possible to add two attributes on the same line. Therefore it is not possible to combine the two lines as you suggested, i.e. it is not possible to shorten a configuration of just these two lines. However, it is still possible to shorten configuration, if you have a longer list of IP addresses.

Since you have Apache 2.4, you could use [mod_macro](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_macro.html) by first creating a macro like this:

```
<Macro AddTrustedIP $ip>
    SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For ^($ip) TRUSTED_IPS
    SetEnvIf X-Real-IP ^($ip) TRUSTED_IPS
</Macro>
```

And then use it like this for every IP:

```
Use AddTrustedIP 91\.148\.158\.226
Use AddTrustedIP 77\.70\.95\.131
```